# How to bind dynamic variable inside pyspark selectExpr?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to bind dynamic variable in PySpark `selectExpr`.

Code:

```
name = "random_string"

df.selectExpr("variable_name as $name")
```

And this throws error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use standard string formatting:

```
df.selectExpr(f"variable_name as {name}")
```

in Python 3.6 or later, or

```
df.selectExpr("variable_name as {}".format(name))
```

before.

Comment: this solution also worked for me inside a F.expr() which was great! I.e. F.expr(f"LEFT( CAST( {dynamic_column_name} AS STRING), 3 )")

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
df.selectExpr(f"variable_name as " + name)
```

and it is working.